# Parameters missing when the java code is compiled

Tags: java

I have a code like

```
private List<xyzClass> fieldName;

public List<xyzClass> getFieldName(){
    return fieldName;
}

public void setFieldName(List<xyzClass> abc){
    this.fieldName= abc;
}
```

but when compiled to java byte code, the parameteres are missing
as below:

```
private List fieldName;

public List getFieldName(){
    return fieldName;
}

public void setFieldName(List abc){
    this.fieldName= abc;
}
```

This is creating issue with SOAP as not able to typecast to xyzClass Exception.

From Eclipse I see the class file created is good
but when I tried command line javac or maven the class file is missing these parameters.

Comment: Pretty sure that's normal. It's known as [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).

Comment: Please make an effort to format your code properly. Paste it, select it, and press Ctrl+K. Only use backticks for inline code.

Comment: Please post the code that's actually failing, and perhaps we can help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html).

Any objects that make use of generics are compiled with bounds. This provides a way to make code "type-safe." As Java is a statically typed language, all variables must be defined beforehand. This provides a method to prevent casts that may result in exceptions, most notably `ClassCastException`s. Any type parameter is replaced with Object. Like so:

Source code:

```
public class Hi<Type> 
{
    public void sayHi(Type t) 
    { 
         ...
```

will be compiled to...

```
public class Hi<Type>
{
    public void sayHi(Object t) 
    {
        ...
```

This of course varies when you impose a restriction on the generic, most notably when using the `extends` keyword. For example:

```
public class Hi<Type extends Number>
{
    public void sayHi(Number t) 
    {
        ...
```

Comment: This is true, except after compiling the `<..>` in the class name will not be there.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson Yes, you are right. I mostly included that for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

This is as a result of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Basically java uses the generics to confirm that you are not violating the type constraints during compile time. All the generics are then removed and replaced with the highest class in the inheritance hierarchy. This will default to `Object` but if you say `<T extends ParentClass>` (for example) the `T` generics will be replaced with `ParentClass`.

Comment: You're right, but also wrong. If an `extends` keyword is used to declare a restriction on the generic, the generic is not replaced with `Object` but rather, the base class that the generic is required to be. `class<T extends Number` will replace any `T`s in the code with `Number`, and not `Object`.